# How to send email with image icon displayed in body in android

Tags: android, html, html-email

I have a task about embed an icon in Gmail body with HTML  tag. But when i do, it only display an image with the text OBJ inside (as same as [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffc/index.htm))
I wonder that does Android support displaying image in Gmail body android?
Here is my code:

```
String htmlSendMail = "<img src= " + (char) 34 + status.getUser().getProfileImageURLHttps() + (char) 34 + " />";
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, 
                       "Tweet from " + name + "(@" + screenName + ")");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(htmlSendMail));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail via..."));
```

[image: My screenshot]

Comment: please!! have a look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604498/android-how-to-send-an-image-as-email-attachment-from-application) post.

Comment: thank for your attendence, RDC. 
But i mention about embed image (get from Internet with link was contained in <img> tag, not from SD Card).