# Attach image from ImageView to mail

Tags: java, android

I have a `fragment` in which it is supposed to capture an image and set it in an `imageview` and then send that image to a specific mail.

I got the first part, where I can capture the image and display it in the `imageview`.

But sending that image to another person via mail is not working.

Any help please

Comment: Have you tried this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604498/android-how-to-send-an-image-as-email-attachment-from-application

Answer (score 1):

Use this

First of all enable drawing cache enabled property on `imageview`

```
 final Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
```

> on Button click to share do this

```
 File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "AppNameFolder");

            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }

            final File img = new File(dir, "image" + ".jpg");
            if (img.exists()) {
                img.delete();
            }
            final OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(img);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/*");
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, getPackageName() + ".my.package.name.provider", img);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photoURI);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share image"));
```

**Note:-**
Make sure you have used File Provider and Read/Write Persmissions also

```
</application>
   ....
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="android.getqardio.com.gmslocationtest"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
</application>
```

where `xml/provider_paths` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path
        name="share"
        path="external_files"/>
</paths>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send image as an attachment via mail by using below code:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"abc@gmail.com"});
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Image as an attachment via mail");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(pic));
                i.setType("image/png");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Share an Image"));
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: The code seems ok but for `>=24` version you need to use file provider while getting file from Uri.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap icon = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bytes);
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Uri screenshotUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/jpg");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "share image"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
the below code helped me solve the above problem. 

Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
                    intent.setType("image/png");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"abc@gmail.com"});
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Identification");
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+mCurrentPhotoPath));
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, str_mobile+","+str_mail);

                    try
                    {
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Send mail..."));
 }
                    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"THERE ARE NO EMAIL CLIENTS INSTALLED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
```